# Relaciones no funcionan para algunos registros en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Tengo dos tablas en la base de datos, una de frases y otra de usuarios, donde un usuario puede tener muchas frases y esa frase solo pertenecer a un usuario.

He poblado mi base de datos con factory para hacer algunas pruebas, pero me he dado cuenta que para algunos registros sus relaciones no se cargan, tampoco de forma inversa (Phrases => User ; User => Phrases). Esto pasa solo con algunos registros, lo cual se me hace bastante raro.

He comprobado como están los registros que no cargan su relación en la base de datos y se ven bien, relacionados bajo una foreign key not null y sin problemas para hacer el match en SQL.

**Relaciones**

```
// Phrases
public function User() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

// User
public function Phrases() : HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(Phrase::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Consulta:

```
App\Models\User::with('Phrases')->where('id','74e21510-b466-4376-8ad5-2950830853fa')->first();
```

```
App\Models\Phrase::with('User')->where('id',573)->first();
```

**Nota:** Al llamar a los modelos por separados (Modelos que no cargan sus relaciones), ambos existen y se muestran sin inconvenientes.

¿Qué podría estar fallando?¿Por qué solo pasa con algunos modelos y no con todos?

*Laravel 8.x*

Comment: @BetaM Si, el usuario en cuestión tiene 10 frases registradas, mis factory seleccionan registros existentes aleatorios para relacionar. 

La consulta como tal está en graphql, pero a la hora de debuguear las relaciones me di cuenta que el problema está ahí y solo pasa con algunos registros en particular. (He agregado las consultas entre modelos que utilicé para probar las relaciones)

Comment: Si, desactivé el autoincrement y definí mi primary key. ````protected $primaryKey = 'id'; public $incrementing = false;````

Comment: Efectivamente, eso ha solucionado mi problema. Muchas Gracias!  Seria de utilidad si lo compartes como respuesta, ya que es un "error" bastante escondido entre las relaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado el valor que veo en tu consulta para la llave primaria del modelo `user` considero que se deben generar en dicha clase algunos cambios.

Para lo anterior mencionado la documentación de Eloquent, en su apartado de convenciones de modelos<sup>1</sup> nos indica que:

- Si la llave primaria no tiene el nombre esperado que es `id` entonces debemos declarar una propiedad en dicho modelo que le *ayude a Eloquent* a determinarla (**al momento esta no parece ser tu situación pero conviene tenerlo presente si es que aplica**).

  ```
  protected $primaryKey = 'nombre_llave_primaria';
  ```
- Si la llave primaria no es un entero auto incremental entonces debemos declarar una propiedad en la clase que lo indique así:

  ```
  public $incrementing = false;
  ```
- Por último si la llave primaria se apoya en un tipo de dato distinto de un entero, entonces debes indicarlo también de esta forma en la clase:

  ```
  protected $keyType = 'string';
  ```

**Referencias**

- [Convenciones de modelos en Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys)